Python encoding issues when reading files on Windows
I developed a script, that reads files in Python, the file is an export of a outlook message I don't think is very important for the matter but I mention just in case.
The thing is I developed the script on Linux I read the file with 0 issues. Just regular reading of a file.
fileHandler = open("/" + fileName,"r")
fileContent = fileHandler.read()
print(fileContent)

But when I tried to run the same script on the same file in Windows I get an error. (latest version installed from the official web page) https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in byte position 7997: invalid continuation byte

I tried adding encoding ISO-8859-1 when opening the file. Which no longer throws an exception but, when I print the file content is complete gibberish
fileHandler = open("/" + fileName,"r", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

Additionally I tried to figure out which encoding has the file by running this script in Linux, and I get "us-ascii" as a result, but if add that to the encoding I get a very similar error.
blob = open("filename.msg","rb").read()
m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME_ENCODING)
m.load()
encoding = m.buffer(blob)
print(encoding)

The error must be something related to the encoding of the console, but I could not figure out how to fix it. I'm not very experienced on Windows so I ran out of ideas.
I expected to read the file normally as in Linux but I got errors, and issues with the file content.

print(fileHandler.encoding) on both systems to see what the implicit encoding is. If they're the same, then the file is likely not actually the same on both systems (which you can figure out by a diff, or a checksum).

Console encoding on Windows is another thing – I recommend setting up UTF-8 mode.

The default file encoding is different on those OSs. Explicitly declare the encoding when writing and reading files. encoding='utf8' is recommended

Outlook messages are gibberish. If you want to extract information from this proprietary format, there are third-party libraries for that, but the format is horrible.

Many MS products include a byte order mark when writing unicode. I might try opening with the parameter encoding="utf-8-sig".

I'm going to try what you said in the comments, one question is can you set up UTF-8 mode without an environment variables, I cannot edit them in the computer I need to execute the script, that sucks to be honest but it's a work computer which  I don't have "root" access.
